# Applying CSS to navigation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 navigation buttons and i am designing a single page vertical site..

When user clicks button 1, i wish to highlight it by applying CSS which is pretty simple.. But then if user clicks button3 then how do i apply same CSS to that button(highlight) and remove the CSS which i had applied to button1(unhighlight)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you have this for html part:

```
<ul id="nav_bar">
    <li id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="item4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

And you have this for css:

```
#nav_bar li {
    // some style here
}

.nav_item_clicked {
    // something else here
}
```

And the jQuery part:

```
$("#nav_bar li").click(function() {
    $("#nav_bar li").removeClass("nav_item_clicked");
    $(this).addClass("nav_item_clicked");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Guanlun.. Never thought it was that simple..your code is fine :)

Answer (score 2):

[http://jsfiddle.net/v6LA9/](http://jsfiddle.net/v6LA9/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
       $('button').removeClass("selected");
       $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
})​
```

This is a function affection all you button elements - it will remove the "selected class from all the buttons and add it to the clicked button.

Comment: **+1** For being the first with ***The Correct Answer***.

Comment: My html code is

 <ul id="example-two">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>